# Determining the numerical value of the parameters of a Moving Average process

Tags: estimation, moving-average, acf-pacf

Is it possible to determine the numerical value of the parameters of a moving average process just by looking at the correlogram (Autocorrelation function and Partial Autocorrelation function) of the model?

Suppose we have a simple $MA(1)$ process:
\begin{equation}
y_{t} = \epsilon_{t}+\alpha\epsilon_{t-1}
\end{equation}
with $\epsilon_{t} \sim WN(0, \sigma^{2}_{\epsilon})$.

Just by looking at the Autocorrelation function and Partial Autocorrelation function of the process without estimating a proper regression, can we derive the value of $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

I computed the correlation between $y_{t}$ and $y_{t-1}$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
Cov(y_{t}, y_{t-1})=E[y_{t}y_{t-1}]-E[y_{t}]E[y_{t-1}]=E[y_{t}y_{t-1}] = E[(\epsilon_{t}+\alpha \epsilon_{t-1})(\epsilon_{t-1}+\alpha \epsilon_{t-2})] = E[\alpha \epsilon_{t-1}^{2}] = \alpha \sigma^{2}_{\epsilon}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
Var(y_{t})=Var(y_{t-1})=\sigma^{2}_{\epsilon}+\alpha^{2}\sigma^{2}_{\epsilon}=\sigma^{2}_{\epsilon}(1-\alpha^2)
\end{equation}
Therefore:
\begin{equation}
Corr(y_{t}, y_{t-1})=\frac{Cov(y_{t}, y_{t-1})}{Var(y_{t})} = \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha^2}
\end{equation}
From wich I can get the value of alpha.

Thank you for the intuition!